# What is content of chlorine in pyrene?

Tags: organic-chemistry

> There is no chlorine atom in pyrene, still it have more chlorine content than gammexane.

Please explain how I can find chlorine content in pyrene.

I found these links on the Internet:

1. [Rankerer](https://rankerer.com/question/chemistry/H93yoNOt9rxO/which-of-the-following-has-highest-chlorine-content)
2. [StudyAdda](https://www.studyadda.com/question-bank/critical-thinking/1400/103133)
3. [Several other links on a Google search](https://www.google.com/search?safe=active&client=firefox-b-ab&ei=VYg3W4-tEojzvgSyi4XADw&q=which%20one%20of%20the%20following%20has%20highest%20chlorine%20content%20%3F%20&oq=which%20one%20of%20the%20following%20has%20highest%20chlorine%20content%20%3F%20&gs_l=psy-ab.12...3242.3242.0.4751.1.1.0.0.0.0.504.504.5-1.1.0....0...1c..64.psy-ab..0.0.0....0.VWLQGjZP8_Y)

Can anyone please explain this fact?

Comment: How? Just like said in the first part of your phrase. Have you seen the structural formula of pyrene? Have you seen a chlorine atom there? No? Guess why? Because _it is not there_. Like, _really_ not there.

Comment: @IvanNeretin Sir, I know that pyrene is a 4 phenyl ring organic compound, but in a textbook that's widely used in India, it is mentioned that "CCl4 is used in fire extinguishers as pyrene" It isn't clear, but that's probably where the doubt arises as to why there's chlorine in pyrene

Comment: Then they must be using the word "pyrene" in a different sense.

Comment: "pyre" relates to fire. This is clearly a trade name that should not be interpreted chemically. More about the Pyrene Fire Extinguisher Compnay can be found here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Pyrene_Company_Limited

Comment: @IvanNeretin yaa i do agree with your points ,but i found same thing too on internet -E.G--1)   https://neetlab.com/questions/which-of-the-following-has-highest-chlorine-content/     2: https://rankerer.com/question/chemistry/H93yoNOt9rxO/which-of-the-following-has-highest-chlorine-content              3: https://www.studyadda.com/question-bank/critical-thinking/1400/103133    etc. many more links are there where i found same answer but no explaination

Comment: Question 1 asks about trade-named products. The question clearly refers to the contents of a Pyrene fire extinguisher i.e. carbon tetrachloride.

Comment: no i m not asking anything related to "fire extinguisher pyrene" i asked different question please prefer to link i provided in question

Comment: this question is correct i found so many links of this question on GOOGLE please just click on link provided above one time before downvoting my question

Comment: The answer provided by your search is not correct!! I suggest you rephrase your question or it will be closed,

Comment: @waylander did u checked link provided in question

Comment: @waylander this question is on Google how could so many website on Google show wrong question

Comment: Because tbey all copy on wrong answer perhaps. Pyrene is a 4 ring all carbon compound with no Chlorine content. I very strongly suspect that the answers you are seeing relate to a proprietary compound for fire extinguishers which is also called Pyrene.

Comment: This is a great misconception in most Indian books around here. I think it would be good if we clear it up in the answers rather than close down this question. || @RafaelNadal the links you've provided are from Indian sites only,  and you can bring thousands of such links, they'd all be wrong because they all copy from each other. The authoritative source is the Wikipedia article https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pyrene

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually i think it's a confusion because there was a [company](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Pyrene_Company_Limited) in the times of World war 2 known as Pyrene Company limited which used to manufature brass containered fire extinguishers in which carbon tetra chloride i.e. CCl4 . and hence due to this confusion some books says that it has high concentration of chlorine.

Comment: sir please prefer to link i had provided

Comment: yeah i have taken a look over that link, it's just that some people confuse pyrene ltd with actual compound pyrene and that's why the answer given to that question is pyrene, actual answer to that question should be gammaxene..